# How to handle validation messages returned by Sails JS?

Tags: javascript, validation, sails.js

Hope you are doing great!!

I am working on SailsJS web-app and using actions structure for controllers.

This is my `user/login` action:

```
  module.exports = {
    friendlyName: 'Login',

    description: 'Login user.',

    inputs: {
      email: {
        description: 'user email.',
        type: 'string',
        required: true
      },
      password: {
        description: 'user password.',
        type: 'string',
        required: true
      }
    },

    exits: {
      success: {
        statusCode: 200,
        responseType: 'view',
      },       
    },

    fn: async function (inputs, exits) {
      // All done.
      return 'hello world';
    }
  };
```

This is the login form html code:

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="valign-wrapper">
          <div class="col s6 z-depth-4 card-panel">
            <form class="col s12 login-form" method="POST" action="/login">
              <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= _csrf %>" />
              <div class="card-content">
                <h5 class="card-title center-align">Login</h5>
                <div class="row margin">
                  <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <input id="email" type="email" class="validate">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback" v-if="formErrors.emailAddress">Please provide a valid email address.</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row margin">
                  <div class="input-field col s12 right">
                    <input id="password" type="password" class="validate">
                    <label for="email">Password</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light right" type="submit" name="action">Login</button>
                </div>            
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Whenever, I am submitting blank form I get this following error:

```
    {
      "code": "E_MISSING_OR_INVALID_PARAMS",
      "problems": [
        "\"email\" is required, but it was not defined.",
        "\"password\" is required, but it was not defined."
      ],
      "message": "The server could not fulfill this request (`POST /login`) due to 2 missing or invalid parameters.  **The following additional tip will not be shown in production**:  Tip: Check your client-side code to make sure that the request data it sends matches the expectations of the corresponding parameters in your server-side route/action.  Also check that your client-side code sends data for every required parameter.  Finally, for programmatically-parseable details about each validation error, `.problems`. "
    }
```

Now, the issue is that I am unable to find a way to handle this error in prettier way.

I hope one of you can guide me on the right path.

Thank You,

Comment: I created a hook that parses errors such as this and adds a human readable `errorMessage` to the the response in controller by calling function `sails.hooks.error.humanize(err)`. I can share the code if you want. Which version of sails are you using(does it support hooks)?

Comment: I am using the latest version, 1.0

Answer (score 4):

U can transform error in api/responses/badRequest

```
module.exports = async function badRequest(data) {
  const status = 400;

  if (data.code && data.code === 'E_MISSING_OR_INVALID_PARAMS'){
    return this.res.status(status).json({
      code: 'My code',
      message: 'My message',
      whateva: 'Bla bla'
    });
  }

  return this.res.status(status).json(data);
};
```

I have a custom project and I need the same thing u requested. I made npm package who take an error object and make it prettier for frontend. Something like this:

```
module.exports = async function badRequest(data) {

  const formatError = require('myFormatError');
  const {status, response}= formatError(data);

  return this.res.status(status).json(response);

};
```

It doesn't need to be npm, u can make some function. I hope u were looking for this.

Comment: Thank you, for your efforts. Your, code snippet handled it very well. But, can we pass these errors back to the view? If yes, then how can we achieve this?

Comment: Sure, you can use `return res. view ('pathToView', {error: response});` in api/responses/*. But you need to handle an error object in view. I recommend you some client side validation for form u sending.

Answer (score 0):

Using the same error object to display will be a mistake because in production technical errors will be stripped off by the toJson method.

The best way to handle the error is to write a custom one. such as

```
  module.exports = {
    friendlyName: 'Login',

    description: 'Login user.',

    inputs: {
      email: {
        description: 'user email.',
        type: 'string'

      },
      password: {
        description: 'user password.',
        type: 'string'

      }
    },

    exits: {
      success: {
        statusCode: 200,
        responseType: 'view',
      },
      badrequest:{
        statusCode: 400,
        responseType: 'view',
      }
    },

    fn: async function (inputs, exits) {
      try{
       if(!inputs.email || !inputs.password){
       return exits.badrequest({code: 'PARAM_MISSING', message: 'Email/Password is missing'});
       }
        // all good
        return exits.success({/* object containing information realted to success*/});
      }
      catch(e){
         return exists.error(e);
        }
      }

    }
  };
```

Comment: thank you for the making an effort, but the irony is code never enters in `fn: async function` it throws error even before entering in it.

Comment: @BlueSuiter thankyou for pointing it out. Only solution I can think of is to remove required param and test it manually. Else, I think you have to handle the error and message in the view itself. I have modified the code as per it.

Comment: so that means required parameter is provided just to make fool of developers. It is useless?

Comment: @BlueSuiter there are many bad decision by sails team. I think, this is only useful when you are using this to return JSON response. as API service.